# Logarithmic Condensation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm trying to find to solve for $y$ on the following problem:

> If $\ln{(y)} = -2 \ln{(x)} - x + \ln{c}$, then $y=$

How do I condense the $-x$ to get it into the form of

$ \ln{(y)} =  \ln{(answer)} $

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to multiply the $x$ term by $\ln(\text{something})$ so that we can apply log laws:
\begin{align*}
-2\ln x - x + \ln(c) &= -2\ln x - x(\color{red}{1}) + \ln(c) \\
&= (-2)\ln x + (-x)\color{red}{\ln(e)} + \ln(c) \\
&= \ln(x^{-2}) + \ln(e^{-x}) + \ln (c) \\
&= \ln(x^{-2} \cdot e^{-x} \cdot c) \\
&= \ln\left(\dfrac{c}{x^2 e^x}\right) \\
\end{align*}
Alternatively, you could solve for $y$ directly by exponentiating both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $e$ to the power of each side, you get $y=x^{-2}e^{-x}c$, now take the log of each side.